# Linux - Test the write speed of an NTFS HDD USB drive

Tags: linux, performance, hard-drive, ntfs

I have a Debian box with an USB HDD drive formated in NTFS connected to it. I would like to test the write speed of it because with samba, when I upload files to it from my Windows 7 laptop, I got some scary performances (1 MB/s).

The concern here is that the drive is mounted in NTFS.

Answer (score 3):

You can test the drive speed with this command:

> hdparm -t -T /dev/(drive)

But if the speed is slow that doesnt means that is it hard drive, which is the issue. Also check your network connectivity (like lenght of cable, the duplex speed of the ethernet interfaces etc) also check logs if there are any errors.

Comment: Im using wifi 802.11g, maybe that's why ?

Comment: yes it can be. Test the bandwidth of connection.